# Difficulties with axios POST request on material-ui & Django

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, material-ui, crud

I am working a project with react.js & material-table as frontend, and django as backend. Currently, I am trying to perform CRUD operations on the material-table. The axios PUT and DELETE requests went pretty well. However, I have some problem with the axios post request. My code below:

```
export default function DataWorker() {
  
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState({
    data: [
      {
        id: "",
        position: "",
        defect: "",
        tool: ""
      }
    ]
  });

  const [state] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: "Position", 
        field: "position",
        width: 150,
        // lookup: { 1: "Position 1", 2: "Position 2", 3: "Position 3"}, 
        cellStyle: { textAlign: "center" } 
      },

      { title: "Defect Type", 
        field: "defect",
        width: 150,
        // lookup: { 1: "None", 2: "Spalling", 3: "Scratch", 4: "Crack"},
        cellStyle: { textAlign: "center" }
      },

      { title: "Tool Decision", 
        field: "tool", 
        width: 150,
        // lookup: { 1: "None", 2: "Tool 1", 3: "Tool 2", 4: "Tool 3"},
        cellStyle: { textAlign: "center" } 
      }
    ]
  });

  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/manual_ver_data/"

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      let data = [];
      response.data.forEach(el => {
        data.push({
          id: el.id,
          position: el.position,
          defect: el.defect,
          tool: el.tool
        });
      });
      setEntries({ data: data });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      components={{
        Toolbar: props => (
          <div style={{ color: "#005005" }}>
            <MTableToolbar {...props} /> 
          </div>
        )
      }}

      title="Manual Verification Label"
      columns={state.columns}
      data={entries.data}
      options={{
        sorting: false,
        draggable: false,
        emptyRowsWhenPaging: false,
        pageSize: 3,
        actionsColumnIndex: -1,
        pageSizeOptions: [3],
        minBodyHeight: 225,
        maxBodyHeight: 225,
        searchFieldStyle: {
          width: 200,
        },
        headerStyle: {
          color: "#212121",
          backgroundColor: "#4caf50",
          textAlign: "center",
        },
        tableLayout: "fixed"
      }}

      localization={{
        header: {
          actions: "Edit"
        }
      }}
      
      editable={{
        onRowAdd: (newData) =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
            const data = [...entries.data]
            axios.post(url, newData)
            .then(res => console.log(res));
          setEntries({ ...entries, data })
          }, 600)
        }),

        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
            const data = [...entries.data];
            data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
            axios.put(url + entries.data[data.indexOf(newData)].id + "/", newData)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));
          setEntries({ ...entries, data });
          }, 600)
        }),

        onRowDelete: oldData =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
            const data = [...entries.data];
            let deleteDataId = entries.data[entries.data.indexOf(oldData)].id
            data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
            axios.delete(url + deleteDataId + "/")
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));
          setEntries({ ...entries, data });
          }, 600);
        })
      }}
    />
  )
};
```

I am using the "id" column as an index to perform PUT and DELETE request, everything was fine because the "id" was automatically generated when I create a data with django admin.

But my method was flaw as I don't have access to the "id" of the new data with axios POST request before I create one in django admin. As a result, my code can still perform a POST request but it will not render the newly created data immediately, I have to refresh it in order to show it. Can anybody tell me what I can do to better my axios POST request, and render the new data without refreshing?

I have solved the problem by including the below code in view.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def TableViewList(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TabelSerializer(data=request.data)
        
        
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Also, including the axios callback function in the onRowAdd:

```
            const data = [...entries.data];
            const populateData = (axiosResponse) => {data.push(axiosResponse)}
            axiosCallBack(populateData)

            function axiosCallBack (populateData) {
              axios.post(url, newData)
              .then(function(res){
                populateData(res.data)
              })  
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to have django include the newly created object in the `post` response. You can then access it from the axios callback and add it to your data array.